# Representation theory of symmetric group for dummies

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, soft-question, symmetric-groups

I have to grade a master project on representations of symmetric groups (char $0$) third time in my life and finally I came to a conclusion that I have to get a grasp of the matter. I am aware of plenty of sources on the topic, such as Lecture 4 in Fulton Harris, but to my shame I don't find these sources user-friendly (far too many things left unproved). So here is a question:

Are you aware of some nice sources on representations of symmetric group (in char $0$) that are user friendly? Maybe some online videos?

This topic seems to be really beautiful, with huge amount of applications and connections to other bits of maths, so I believe there must be somewhere something pedagogical and user-friendly...

Comment: the books by prasad and sagan are quite user friendly if you mean representation theory in characteristic zero.

Comment: Thanks Mare, I can't google them. Could you give the reference?

Comment: Representation Theory : A Combinational Viewpoint
by Amritanshu Prasad, Cambridge studies in applied mathematics

Comment: and The Symmetric Group: Representations, Combinatorial Algorithms, and Symmetric Functions
by Bruce Sagan, Springer

Comment: You can also read http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi333.pdf.

Comment: I find books by Gordon James readable ( there is also a book by James  and Kerber), though maybe he goes into the modular theory more that you would want.

Comment: Stanley's 2nd volume of http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ contains quite a bit on symmetric functions, which might be almost all you need...

Comment: In my list of lecture notes on algebraic combinatorics at m.se ( http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454420/ ), there is a section about Young tableaux and symmetric groups. This is not literally all about symmetric group representations, but some of the sources are very much readable. For example, the Wildon notes are very nice (I've read them). The book by Ceccherini-Silberstein, Scarabotti and Tolli appears quite readable as well.